# How to quit a script but not the GUI application

Tags: python, qt

I have got a GUI aplication which includes five python scripts.

I  have already found an error in the IO data, and then I'd like to include a escape condition to quit the python script and show a QT message but stay the GUI application.

one of the scripts

```
        if len(Numero_Unidades) != 1:
            quit()
        else:
            pass

        block
```

but it quits  python

and I want to stay in the GUI application, maintaining the main window open.

```
if self.ui.radioButton3.isChecked()== True: 
        myscript.myscript()
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self,'message')
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you aware of the [module](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) concept of python?

Comment: Yes, I am. The script myscript is imported into the GUI application

Comment: There's only one application running. If you quit, you obviously have no GUI.

Comment: But is it possible to skip the rest of the script maintaining the GUI 'alive' ?

Comment: I have to rewrite the script including an error, but at the moment I need a solution without making any change in the script

Comment: Fine. Then turn the quit() call in the scripts into a `raise` (whatever you want to raise) and `quit()` on that exception just in the modules own `if __name__ = '__main__'` part.

Comment: Are you just running the Main routine of the Script or are you running in functions? Be aware that just running main routines is a very bad habit for interaction of multiple script files. If you do not want to use classes (whyever) at least use functions and use their return command to exit a function and not your whole python process.

Comment: The script is an imported module.

Comment: Short answer to a detailed question.  Is the script structured by classes and function definitions or is it just plain non-structured script code?

Answer (score 0):

You can start another python process to launch your script

By using `os.system("script.py")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `quit()` function is the built-in [quit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#quit), you can monkey-patch it and raise an error instead of quitting the whole appliaction:

```
import myscript
import __builtin__

def myquit():
    raise RuntimeError('script quit!')

__builtin__.quit = myquit

try:
    myscript.myscript()
except RuntimeError as exception:
    print(exception)
else:
    print('keep calm and carry on')
```